# Constraint modeling in Pyomo with if statement

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, pyomo, piecewise

I am currently working on an optimization modeling, in which I have the following constraint:

[image]

In the equation, pj, n, Nj, and rho are parameters, whereas sj is positive integer variable

Based on the following article, https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6069/use-if-statements-when-defining-a-constraint-in-pyomo, I know that modeling a constraint with endogenous if statement should not be conducted. Nonetheless, I couldn't think of a way to make piecewise constraints based on this equation.

Should anyone can help me on this is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are attempting to make an integer based NLP where you have an integer variable that is:  in a denominator, in a factorial, in an exponent, in a summation limit, and in a piecewise condition in just one of the constraints?

Comment: I am not sure,  the constraint is basically derived from the queueing problem M/M/c/c, was just wondering if it can be modeled using Pyomo

Comment: I don't think so...  You can't express factorial, and using a variable as a summation limit doesn't work either.  Perhaps somebody will suggest a different framework to attack this.  Any queueing work that I've looked at was always wrangled with simulation and some kind of design of experiments.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I guess I'd just take a look for another approach in performing this